# Is it possible to actually cast the return value of std::bind to an std::function without construction?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, stl

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348681/how-to-avoid-explicit-cast-with-stdbind-temporary-objects), the OP claims that the third line in the `main` function is casting the return value of `std::bind` to `std::function`.

However, it looks like a simple constructor call to me.

Is there a legitimate way to actually **cast** the return value of `std::bind` to `std::function` without constructing a new object?

Alternately, is it kosher (not undefined behavior) to cast the the address of a return value of `std::bind` to `std::function*` and then invoke it by deferencing it?

Assume I know the appropriate template parameters for `std::function`. That is, assume they are the same template parameters which would have been used if we were constructing an instance of `std::function` from the return value of `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard calls this an explicit type conversion with functional notation. Essentially it is used to construct a value of the specified type. Although it may look like a constructor call, there's actually no way to directly call a constructor in C++.

> Is there a legitimate way to actually cast the return value of std::bind to std::function without constructing a new object?

No. The return type of `std::bind` is unspecified; it can return anything so long as it provides the correct operations and semantics. There's no way you could just consider it as a `std::function` in a portable manner.

> Alternately, is it kosher (not undefined behavior) to cast the the address of a return value of std::bind to std::function* and then invoke it by deferencing it?

No, that's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Type of `std::bind` expression is different from `std::function` type. In some cases, it cannot even be converted to `std::function`. So, no, you cannot cast bind object to `std::function` without constructing. Compiler can allow implicit conversion, though.

Same applies to lambda expression.

Comment: In what case can it not be converted? I am currently under the understanding that it can always be converted but if I misread the standard I would like to know.

Comment: if you bind with value of noncopyable type (`std::unique_ptr`, for instance) by `std::move`. Thus, bind object becomes noncopyable, but `std::function` is.